# Given the coordinates of three vertices, what is a better way to find the area of the triangle?

Tags: area

```
p1 = {x1, y1};
p2 = {x2, y2};
p3 = {x3, y3};
a = EuclideanDistance[p1, p2];
b = EuclideanDistance[p2, p3];
c = EuclideanDistance[p3, p1];
p = (a + b + c)/2;
s = Sqrt[p (p - a) (p - b) (p - c)]
```

for example:

```
p1 = {2, 1};
p2 = {2/3 (5 + 2 Sqrt[2]), 1/3 (-5 - 4 Sqrt[2])};
p3 = {2/3 (5 - 2 Sqrt[2]), 1/3 (-5 + 4 Sqrt[2])};
a = EuclideanDistance[p1, p2];
b = EuclideanDistance[p2, p3];
c = EuclideanDistance[p3, p1];
p = (a + b + c)/2;
s = Sqrt[p (p - a) (p - b) (p - c)] // FullSimplify
```

get the area:

```
(16 Sqrt[2])/9
```

Is there a better way to find the area of a triangle?

Comment: `Area[Triangle[{p1, p2, p3}]]`

Comment: Or `tri = {{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 4}};
TriangleMeasurement[tri, "Area"]`

Comment: It's too shocking. There is such a simple method! Thank you both.

Comment: Please search the documentation as well as this site before asking questions.